# Which Sql server is good to use for university assignments?? Please comment links to download that too.

Tags: sql

Which Sql server is good to use for university assignments?? Please comment links to download that too.

Comment: what do you mean which sql server? the version? install either 32/64 bit 2012/2014 according to your OS. for your assignments, I guess no huge difference between 2012 and 2014

Answer (score 1):

I usually would vote to close this but I would look at [Imagine](https://imagine.microsoft.com/en-us/catalog), formerly DreamSpark, which hosts a ton of software for students to use freely... or just download the [Free Version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) for what ever you want since this is for school. Also, your university *may* offer a licenses of [Developer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-developers) which is free for 2016 (without production data)

Comment: I mean I just downloaded MS SSMS , and i don't know how to connect to the server, in this one , before that i was using BITVISE  to wire queries. Please either help me connect to the server or suggest me anything to write queries in.

Comment: You can research that and find hundreds of examples, videos, and tutorials.